# How to use exhaustMap correctly Angular 7

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular7

The grid is bound to the service using `async`. Using the same service for more than one cases (modes - the `state` changes then) I found out that sometimes the second request finishes first and the fist one finishes after that. The grid then shows the data from the first response, whereas I need it to show the data from the last response. So, I would like to use **exhaustMap** in order to wait response finish before triggering a new request.

Please find my code below.

service.ts

```
public query(token: string, tableName: string, state: any): void {
    console.log("state in query", state);
    this.fetch(token, tableName, state)
        .subscribe((x: any) => {
            console.log("response data", this.data);
            super.next(x);
            this.isLoading = false;
            this.mediatorService.sendMessage("APsRefreshed");
        },
            (err: any) => {
                console.log("err", err);
                this.isLoading = false;
            }
        );
}

public fetch(token: string, tableName: string, state: any): Observable<any> {
    let queryStr = `${toODataString(state)}&$count=true`;
    queryStr = queryStr.replace(/('[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12}')/ig, function (x) {
        return x.substring(1, x.length - 1);
    });
    queryStr = queryStr.replace(/substringof\((.+),(.*?)\)/, "contains($2,$1)");
    const regex = /T00:00:00\.000Z/gi;
    const noTimeZoneQueryStr = queryStr.replace(regex, '');
    let fetchCallResult = this.http
        .get(`${this.BASE_URL}` + `/` + token + `${tableName}&${noTimeZoneQueryStr}`)
        .pipe(
            map((response: any) => ((<any>this.data) = {
                data: response['value'],
                total: parseInt(response['@odata.count'], 10)
            }
            ))
    );
    return fetchCallResult;
}
```

component.ts

```
public initialiseGrid() {
    this.APsService.isLoading = true;
    this.gridViewAPs = this.APsService;
    this.APsService.query(this.token, this.tableName, this.state);
}
```

template.html

```
<kendo-grid #gridView
            [data]="gridViewAPs | async"
            [loading]="APsService.isLoading"
            ...
>
```

Comment: It'd be better if you could provide more information above how the service works. Besides, `exhauseMap` straight up ignore the source observable notifications if the inner observable is still in progress. So you wouldn't get the results from the slower request. What you actually need is `concatMap`.

Comment: @Michael D Thank you. I've got two buttons. Both call initialiseGrid(), while `this.state` changes to show different data each time. If the user presses the first button and after that the second one, if the first response is slower than the second one, the grid shows the first response, whereas I need the second one (cause the second button was hit last). Hmm... You are right. What I actually need is to get the response in the order the requests happened. So, `concatMap` is the right choice? But how should I change my code to achieve the desired functionality?

Comment: I am not familiar with `kendo-grid` and I do not understand this line `this.gridViewAPs = this.APsService;`. So the `kendo-grid` accepts the entire instance of the service as an input?

Comment: Yes that's right. Apart from the actual response (the result in subscription), it accepts that as well (using `async` - https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/data-binding/#toc-indicating-ongoing-data-operations).

Comment: Is it ok, that you use service instance with `async` pipe? Does that service implements Observable interface?

Comment: Isn't it ok to  use service instance with `async` pipe? This is the way they use it here: https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/data-binding/#toc-indicating-ongoing-data-operations

Answer (score 5):

Consider a scenario, where you are making a call to the backend, using a button click. You intend to send the PUT request to the backend whenever the user clicks on the 'Save' button.

So, your code looks like this, initially.

```
  fromEvent(this.saveButton.nativeElement, 'click')
  .pipe(
      concatMap(changes => this.saveCourse(changes))
  ).subscribe();
```

Here, if you keep on using concatMap and click the 'Save' button N number of times in fast speed, N number of requests will be made to backend.

However , if you use a exhaustMap like this:

```
  fromEvent(this.saveButton.nativeElement, 'click')
  .pipe(
      exhaustMap(changes => this.saveCourse(changes))
  ).subscribe();
```

then your request will be sent a lesser number of times.

The reason to use 'exhaustMap' is that the values from the source observables are ignored as long as the inner observable is still in progress.

So in this case, during some of your clicks(which is treated as the source observable), the inner observable(which is the put request) is already in the progress.
Hence these clicks will be ignored.